# Maximum Likelihood: Bias and Efficiency

Tags: maximum-likelihood, bias-variance-tradeoff

I have a basic question but I somehow can't wrap my head around it. It is said that Maximum Likelihood Estimation is unbiased and efficient in large samples. I am also aware that usually there is trade-off between bias and variance.

So my question is: how can ML estimates be both unbiased and efficient at the same time, despite such trade-off?

I would be very appreciative for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

Unbiased estimator has an expected value that equals to the true parameter. An efficient and unbiased estimator has the lowest possible variance among all unbiased estimators.

There exists no trade off between efficiency and bias. What I think you might be referring to is the trade off between variance and bias. There are some biased estimators that have a lower variance than their efficient unbiased counterparts.

Comment: There can be a variance vs bias trade off depending on your criterion for an optimal estimate. For example if mean square error is your criteria a biased estimator could be better than any unbiased one. If your criterion is minimum variance unbiased you are excluding bias estimators. You also don't address the fact that the OP is only considering MLEs & issues involved with them.